# FastCGI error, after started using nginx

Tags: php, yii, nginx, fastcgi

I just started to use a server for my project and I installed nginx on it as a webserver. 
In my development environment I use apache, because in Windows that was much faster to install. I have a PHP project based on Yii-framework.

Since I cloned my source to this server, I get this message, and I couldn't find any solution to solve it:

```
2013/06/19 17:54:33 [error] 21842#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /path/to/file.php on line 23" while reading response header from upstream, client: 85.XXX.YYY.ZZZ, server: example.dk, request: "GET /product/list HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.dk"
```

The `line 23` in that file is a normal array initializing, nothing extra.

```
$models = [];
```

Because of this error, my site returns with status code 500.

My PHP config is untouched.

I couldn't figure out what could cause this. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have >= php 5.4 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$models = [];` to `$models = array();` short array syntax is supported only in php >= 5.4.

Or update your php version.

Comment: yes, I updated it, I just had to restart... -.-

Thanks anyway!